# HashSet adds duplicate objects

Tags: java, set, hashcode

I have a HashSet which stores some Edges in a Graph.
Each Edge has two Nodes.

In the case the graph is undirected, adding the duplicate should fail:

```
Edge a = new Edge(new Node("aa"), new Node("bb"));
Edge duplicate = new Edge(new Node("aa"), new Node("bb"));
```

But in the following example it works:

```
System.out.println(a.equals(duplicate));

Set<Edge> sete = new HashSet<Edge>();
System.out.println(sete.contains(a));
System.out.println(sete.add(a));
System.out.println(sete.contains(duplicate));
System.out.println(sete.add(duplicate));

Output:
true

false
true
false
true
```

EDIT: 
Ok now I've added a hashCode method, that works for directed Edges.
Does someone can help me to compute the hash for undirected Edges?

```
public class Edge {
    private Node first, second;

    @Override
    public /boolean equals(Object ob) {
        if (ob instanceof Edge) {
            Edge edge = (Edge) ob;
            if (first.equals(edge.first)
                    && second.equals(edge.second)
                    || first.equals(edge.second)
                    && second.equals(edge.first))
                return true;
        }
        return false;
   }


    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 17;
        int hashMultiplikator = 79;
        hash = hashMultiplikator * hash
                + first.hashCode();
        hash = hashMultiplikator * hash
                + second.hashCode();
        return hash;
    }
```

Comment: how did you implement equals() and hashCode()?

Comment: did you override `equals` method for `Node`?

Comment: @Sam `.equals()` alone is NOT enough, you must also implement `.hashCode()`; otherwise you break the `Object` contract.

Comment: @fge obviously, that would have been my second question

Comment: show us ur implementation of equals and hashcode

Comment: I thoug equals() would be enough. So I'll implement hashCode too

Comment: @veote `.equals()` alone is never enough. You must override `.hashCode()` when you override `.equals()`. As I already said, this is the `Object` contract, and is the most fundamental contract in all Java.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments...

You must implement `.equals()` and `.hashCode()` for BOTH classes `Edge` and `Node`.

A `HashSet` uses `.hashCode()` to determine the hash bucket in which to place a new entry; if there are already entries in this bucket, it uses `.equals()` on each entry of the bucket to see if the entry already exists.

Since you didn't override any of them, implementations of these methods are the one of `Object`:

- `.hashCode()` is a simple hash over the object's reference address;
- `.equals()` is true if and only if both objects are the same reference (ie, `o1 == o2`).

And this is obviously not what you want!

Answer (score 1):

The only explanation to this phonomenon is Edge.hashCode is incorrect or not overriden. You should have added these lines to your code

```
System.out.println(a.hashCode());
System.out.println(duplicate.hashCode());
```

to know why